# Abstracting the DateTime.Current dependency

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, dependencies, decoupling

Is there a nuget package, or other "standard" that wraps the hard dependency created when your code is coupled to `DateTime.Now`?

I'm seeking guidance on this before writing my own. Albeit that it's trivial to do so, I'd rather use something that exists if it already does as somewhat of a standard.

Comment: @Jason: Avoiding the implicit dependency here is thoroughly worthy. Getting "the current time" is a service like any other dependency. It's *so* much easier to test code which makes that clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose we have a method:

```
public void Foo() {

  var now = DateTime.UtcNow;
  Record(now);
```

The solution i always employ anytime I  need `DateTime.Now` is:

```
public void Foo(DateTime? now = null) {

  Record(now.GetValueOrDefault(DateTime.UtcNow));
```

Answer (score 3):

I very much doubt that there's any nuget package for anything quite so trivial - a single interface and probably two implementations ("system" clock and a fake one for testing).

If you're doing one of these yourself, I would *strongly* consider making the clock return a `DateTimeOffset` instead of a `DateTime`, or *at least* make it wrap `DateTime.UtcNow`... `DateTime.Now` is a problem waiting to happen...

However, [Noda Time](http://noda-time.googlecode.com) contains all of this out of the box. You probably don't want the whole of Noda Time just for this reason, mind you...

(There's a Noda Time nuget package, but it's definitely pre-release. I need to update it to a 0.2 version at some point, but it's *still* not at the v1 level yet. Getting there though...)

---

If you want a *really* cheap-and-cheerful way of expressing the dependency, you could always take a `Func<DateTime>` or `Func<DateTimeOffset>` wherever you normally express dependencies. The interface approach is cleaner though :)

Comment: Could you elaborate on why you would recommend using a DateTimeOffset? I don't believe I've ever had a need to use that class before. Also I took a look at Noda Time and I didn't really see much in usage examples, is there a specific something I should look at to start with?

Comment: @ChrisMarisic: DateTimeOffset is rather less ambiguous than DateTime, which is a pain to work with in terms of having to check whether it's local or universal etc. I don't have many usage examples for Noda Time yet, but if you have a specific operation in mind, I'm happy to write that up as an exmaple (or several). Putting up *real* examples would be fabulous :)

Answer (score 1):

I dont know of any nuget package that does this.  When I've run into this problem I've simply created my own type like this:

```
public static class SystemTime
{
    public static Func<DateTime> Now = () => DateTime.Now;
}
```

That way in your unit tests you can easily change the functionality of Now to return any DateTime you want.

Comment: Ick - can't say I like that approach myself. This is a dependency - so make it *obviously* a dependency.

Comment: -1 this is taking the core DateTime.Now dependency and making exactly DateTime2.Now